# Showing Custom Meta in WordPress Quick Edit

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, conditional-statements, custom-post-type

I have a WordPress website that showcases multiple teams, using a custom post type, where team members appear in more than one team. I'm using a plugin that allows me to set a custom order for each individual team member for each individual team, but it's become a hassle having to edit each member's order within their post. I want to enable the custom meta text fields that handle the members' orders on quick edit. The plugin already allows you to set a custom order through quick edit by default, but this just addresses one team.

**The Problem:**

- I have a team member named John Doe that is both part of the
  leadership team and also part of the accounting team.
- He needs to be listed as the 1st one on the accounting team because he is head of that department
- However, for the leadership team, John Doe needs to appear as 3rd
- Setting the default custom order number to either 1 or 3 would cause him to not appear correctly on one of the teams. 1, causing him to show up as 1st in the leadership team, or 3 causing him to show up 3rd in the accounting team. Just can't rely on one order number here.
- Luckily the plugin has the capability to use custom metas that you can add to each individual team to custom order team members
- I have the leadership team using John Doe's meta "MTS Order Leadership" = 3 and another custom meta "MTS Order Accounting"= 1. Works great on the frontend.
- But time-consuming on the backend.

**This is how it works now:**
[Default columns in custom post type has one custom order field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13C2H.jpg) and when you click on the pencil icon to edit it, it opens up the quick edit:
[Where it then lets you enter a number in a text field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0moOM.jpg)

**What I need it to do**
Using these custom metas found in the individual team member's post: [custom metas being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1wzb.jpg) I need the same type of functionality, with the pencil icon still (no text field or number needs to appear at first). But when you click on the pencil icon, quick edit pulls up still and you see something similar to this(note: this is something I photoshopped together. This is the functionality I need to achieve and cannot recreate myself in the actual code): [Where you can choose a team from a dropdown that lists all the custom metas I created, and with conditional logic, the corresponding order text field pulls up with the right number value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ioo9Z.jpg) Here you would have the chance to change it or enter in a value, if there wasn't one already.

I'm comfortable adding php and modifying it but I have no idea how to achieve this without guidance.  The plugin developer hasn't responded to any of my messages, so that's not an option. The name of the plugin is Modern Team Showcase.

---

Here is the code that makes the order field appear, if this helps:

```
/**
 * Add a new column called Order for the all members page
 */
function mts_cpt_columns($columns) {
  if( current_user_can( WMTS_EDITING_CAP ) ){
    $new_columns = array(
        'order' => __('Order number', 'modern-team-showcase'),
    );
      return array_merge($columns, $new_columns);
  }
  return $columns;
}

add_filter('manage_modernteammembers_posts_columns' , 'mts_cpt_columns');


/**
 * Add a quick edit option for the member order
 */
function display_custom_member_order_quick_edit( $column_name, $post_type ) {
    static $printNonce = TRUE;
    if ( $printNonce ) {
        $printNonce = FALSE;
        wp_nonce_field( 'update-mts-order', 'update-mts-order' );
    }

    ?>
    <fieldset class="inline-edit-col-right inline-edit-order">
      <div class="inline-edit-col column-<?php echo $column_name; ?>">
        <label class="inline-edit-group" style="display: inline-block; background: yellow; padding: 4px 10px;">
        <?php
         switch ( $column_name ) {
         case 'order':
             ?><span class="title">Order number</span><input name="mts-order" type="number" /><?php
             break;
         }
        ?>
        </label>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'quick_edit_custom_box', 'display_custom_member_order_quick_edit', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Add content for the MTS order column
 */
function mts_custom_columns_content( $column, $post_id ) {
    if($column == 'order'){
        $order = get_post_meta($post_id, 'MTS Order', true);
        if( ! $order ) $order = 0;
        echo $order . '<i class="fa fa-pencil wmts_edit_order"></i>';
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_modernteammembers_posts_custom_column' , 'mts_custom_columns_content', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Add content for the MTS order column
 */
function mts_save_quick_edit_data ( $post_id ) {
    $slug = 'modernteammembers';
    if ( isset($_POST['post_type']) && $slug !== $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $_POST += array("{$slug}_edit_nonce" => '');
    if ( ! isset( $_POST["update-mts-order"] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST["update-mts-order"], 'update-mts-order' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['mts-order'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'MTS Order', $_REQUEST['mts-order'] );
    }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'mts_save_quick_edit_data' );

/**
 * Push values into the custom quick edit columns
 */
if ( ! function_exists('wmts_admin_enqueue_quick_edit_script') ) {
    function wmts_admin_enqueue_quick_edit_script( $hook ) {
        if ( 'edit.php' === $hook && isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) && 'modernteammembers' === $_GET['post_type'] ) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'wmts_quick_edit_script', plugins_url('assets/js/quick_edit_script.js', __FILE__), false, null, true );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wmts_admin_enqueue_quick_edit_script' );

/**
 * Make the members sortable by MTS Order
 */
add_filter( 'manage_edit-modernteammembers_sortable_columns', 'wmts_modernteammembers_manage_sortable_columns' );
function wmts_modernteammembers_manage_sortable_columns ( $sortable_columns ) {
   $sortable_columns[ 'order' ] = 'order';
   return $sortable_columns;
}

/**
 * Handle the actual sorting of members
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'manage_modernteammembers_column_sorting', 1 );
function manage_modernteammembers_column_sorting( $query ) {
   if ( $query->is_main_query() && ( $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby' ) ) ) {
      switch( $orderby ) {
         case 'order':
            $query->set( 'meta_key', 'MTS Order' );
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
            break;
      }
   }
}
```

----------- This is the full code within the quick_edit_script.js that is referred to --------------

```
(function($) {

    // we create a copy of the WP inline edit post function
    var $wp_inline_edit = inlineEditPost.edit;

    // and then we overwrite the function with our own code
    inlineEditPost.edit = function( id ) {

        // "call" the original WP edit function
        // we don't want to leave WordPress hanging
        $wp_inline_edit.apply( this, arguments );

        // now we take care of our business

        // get the post ID
        var $post_id = 0;
        if ( typeof( id ) == 'object' ) {
            $post_id = parseInt( this.getId( id ) );
        }

        if ( $post_id > 0 ) {
            // define the edit row
            var $edit_row = $( '#edit-' + $post_id );
            var $post_row = $( '#post-' + $post_id );

            // get the data
            var order = $( '.column-order', $post_row ).text();

            // populate the data
            $( ':input[name="mts-order"]', $edit_row ).val( order );
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. So you have custom code that allows you to change the order of the team members. What needs to be different specifically? And what are the teams? Is that a custom taxonomy? Can you try to explain what you are trying to achieve as an end result?

Comment: @Wesley-Synio Thanks for pointing that out. I've modified my inquiry. & The team members are a custom post type called "modernteammembers" with each post having several custom fields/metadata that handle the order that the team member will appear in. The teams are also custom post types referred to as "modernteamshowcases".

Comment: thanks, could you also add the assets/js/quick_edit_script.js file somewhere so that we can see how the field is currently being filled in the quick edit box?

Comment: @Wesley-Synio Just added the quick_edit js

Comment: Ok, so it's loading from the value that is available in the DOM. I don't think the other order values are available there. There's different approaches you can take. I would probably opt for adding an AJAX call when the quick edit form is opened to retrieve the custom ordering rules and display those in a select box with an input field that changes depending on which one you select.. I would love to help you out in more detail, but it's a bit too complex for me to write out without working on the code.. I hope you can get it working with this info.